# How to get navigation history?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am trying to implement a menu including the most recently visited and most commonly visited pages within the Angular app. How can I get the navigation stack? Or do I need to hook the `navigationStart` event and compile it as it is created?

Comment: What is the scope? Do you want to track most popular pages for the current user? all users? all tabs/windows?

Comment: At the moment Angular doesn't have built-in possibility to get all navigation history. You need to use navigation events to store navigation history for further needs.

Comment: you can store all visited route.
your question answers is [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771781/navigate-to-last-visited-child-route-when-entering-parent-route-angular-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get the full history with a simple method call, but you can track this easily yourself by subscribing to the NavigationEnd.

```
previousUrl: string;
constructor(router: Router) {
  router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log('prev:', this.previousUrl);
    this.previousUrl = e.url;
  });
}
```

In this sample it saves only the previous route, but you could store in an array to save all the previously visited routes.

See also:
[How to determine previous page URL in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular)

Update:

You can use the above code in combination with the code below to subscribe to the NavigationEnd in your service from the start of your application.

```
export class AppModule {
constructor(navigationEndService: NavigationEndService) {
    navigationEndService.init();
}
```

To get hold of the list in other places you could create a getter in the service.

Comment: Question is not about only previous URL, but navigation history or recently visited pages.

Comment: You can't see the full history because Angular uses the browser history mechanism, which does not expose the details of the history.

Comment: It seems like this is the most likely approach. Where would you hook on to the navigationEnd event so that it caught every navigation event - and then how do you reference it to get the value out of the array?

Comment: You can do the above in a service class for example. You could initialize the route event listener in your app.module file so that your service is subscribed to the NavigationEnd event.I updated the answer above.